# Why the command 'java' is executed even when no path is set?

Tags: java, command-prompt

If the path is not set then the command `javac' in command prompt results in

> 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Whereas the command `java` is successfully executed.

Platform: Windows XP

Comment: On which operating system? How was Java installed?

Comment: You have the JRE, but not the JDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*If* this is a Windows machine and you *have* installed the JDK, what's likely happening is that the installer places a copy of java.exe in a system directory that is included in PATH, such as in `C:\WINDOWS\system32`.

The installer does this so you may run Java programs without further setup. The compiler is not given the same treatment, not sure why.

Comment: No, `javac.exe` is not copied to system directories.

Comment: @CodeEnthusiastic Can you check your `System32` and verify this? I happen to have both installed and I didn't find `java.exe` there.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal I can see these files in System 32. java javacpl javaw javaws there. But there is no javac.exe in System32.

Comment: @CodeEnthusiastic Thanks for getting back on this. +1 to you mate.

Answer (score 3):

Probably indicates that the machine has Java Runtime Environment (JRE) installed but not the JDK. `javac` and other Java development related programs like `javadoc`, `jarsigner` etc. are part of the Java Development Kit not JRE.

Comment: @AshishAggarwal, Why, when this is the answer?

Comment: @AshishAggarwal. This is the answer to the question.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I am asking: If I have not set the path then why the command 'java' is executed and why 'javac' not?

Comment: @CodeEnthusiastic run `echo %PATH%` and you would probably find the `jre/bin` dir on your path.

Comment: @DownVoter, This is certainly not an incorrect answer. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If machine has `JRE` then `java` command will work once you get install whole `jdk` it contains path to `javac`.

If `JRE` is only installed then java.exe resides under `PATH` variable something like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.6.0_43\bin` thats why java works. try below command on command prompt.

```
 > echo %PATH%
```